# How do I write a non Velocity test that uses Mongo?

Tags: meteor

I got Velocity to work, and it's cool, but I wish I could run tests on the command line without starting up Meteor. Restarting is slow

I *have* managed to write simple unit tests that I can run with `npm test`, but they don't have access to any Meteor or package code, so I can only write pretty isolated unit tests. Yeah, I can mock out things, but mocking out Mongo seems mad.

Is there a way to write command line tests that can use Mongo and package code?

Comment: Can you link/post the how you run `npm test`s?

Comment: I just cd to the test directory and do `npm test`

The tests have `var expect = require("chai").expect;`, and that's the whole setup, I think.

Comment: i've heard you can run velocity cli, would be good if there was better documentation around that,  I would like to do the same but haven't got it working yet myself.  there is an alternative newer command line testing framework https://github.com/anticoders/gagarin if you want to give it a shot.

Comment: I would say stick with Velocity. They are working on some nice ways to speed it up: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=83dBtU6qy6c

Comment: You can also now run velocity directly from the command line w/ `meteor run --test`.

Comment: The Velocity speedup is about running a lot of tests concurrently. My goal is sort of the opposite. I want to run one test quickly, during TDD. Right now it takes 20 seconds before the tests even start.